# In How Many Ways Hiring Can Be Made?

Tags: combinatorics

I've been trying to solve this question, but no luck. I would really appreciate your help.

In the first place I thought, `8x5=40` for the first question and `8x4=32` for the second question.

```
There are 8 positions to be filled in the company and 5 applicants for each position. 
Only 1 applicant to each of 8 positions has a background.

a) In how many ways these positions can be filled?

b) In how many ways these positions can be filled 
only with people which do not have any background?
```

The link of the screenshot of the question itself,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sm6oQ.png

And also the error I got when I entered 390625,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEu9i.png

Comment: The [education] tag is not meant to be used for questions about mathematics which happened to occur during your own education, but is rather meant to be used for questions about the educational process itself, i.e. about the pedagogy of education.  For example "*How often should tests be administered in order to gauge student involvement and understanding.*"  Such questions are almost always better suited for the math educators stackexchange.  This also does not have to do with finite-groups.

Comment: Can you please explain your reasoning for $8 \cdot 5 = 40$ for the first question?

Comment: As for your question itself, no, both sound incorrect.  First, it should be clarified whether every position's set of applicants is totally disjoint from one another or if there might be some applicants who applied to multiple positions.  Assuming they are in fact disjoint, then approach via [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).  Choose which applicant fills the first position.  You have $5$ choices.  Choose which applicant fills the second position.  You again have $5$ choices.  Choose which applicant fills the third position.  You yet again have $5$ choices, etc..

Comment: Multiply the number of choices for each step together for a final result.  $5\times 5\times 5\times \cdots$

Comment: @MathLover, I thought like, I have 5 different options for the 1 position and then same goes for the second position and so on and so forth until the 8th position. But It turns out to be wrong.

Comment: Yes there are $5$ options for each position but you do not add them. You apply product role as JMoravitz wrote. Take an  example with smaller numbers, say $2$ positions and $3$ candidates for each position. Write them down. See whether you get $6$ or $9$.

Comment: @JMoravitz, I applied 5x5x5x5x5x5x5x5 (which is 5 to the power of 8) for the first question but it is also wrong. I couldn't understand the reason.

Comment: @MathLover, in your case it is 3x3 (3 to the power of 2) which is 9.

Comment: "It is also wrong."  How do you come to that result?  Do you have an answer key you are checking against?

Comment: No it is a software that it tells me my answer is wrong. @JMoravitz

Comment: $5^8$ is the correct answer to the question you have written as I interpret it with basic necessary assumptions.  Either you copied the question incorrectly, left out key necessary details, made an arithmetic mistake or otherwise entered the result into the software in an incorrect way, or the answer they are expecting is wrong.

Comment: Yeah your answer seems logical to me too, let me put the screenshot of the question itself for a more exhaustive comparison. @JMoravitz

Comment: Well I couldn't add the screenshot itself since I am a new user, but you find the link of the screenshot in the post. @JMoravitz

Comment: I also added the error I got when I entered 390625 as the answer. I really appreciate your help. This question is driving me crazy. @JMoravitz

Comment: Don't you have any other ideas? I am desperate :( @JMoravitz

Comment: Check to see if they specified the format in which you should input your answers if it varies from how you input your answers (*e.g. you should have had commas or should have left it as `5^8` or similar*), complain to the website, complain to the teacher, try opening the source code for the website and seeing if you can find what answer they're expecting...  In my experience, websites like this are notoriously bad at actually understanding the math and are just in it to make a quick buck.

Comment: You're totally right... But it just wants a plain decimal number without any dots or commas. @JMoravitz

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, you have 8 positions and 5 options per position, this means that you can select 5 candidates for the first, 5 candidates for the second position, and so on. Now, by taking $5 \times 5 \times ... \times 5 = 5^8 = 390625$ you will find all possible combinations since for each position you will have to consider all other possibilities for the other positions.

The second question is solved similarly, here you only have 4 candidates per position, hence $4^8$ = 65536 options.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I entered the same results but the software says it is wrong... :( @teun

Comment: That is strange since this should be the solution according to the feedback the software gave you in the second screenshot.

Comment: Exactly, still couldn't figure out the reason :( @teun